# Difference between closer and closely

Tags: adverbs

In the following sentence, should I use **closely** or **closer** ?

> We feel the past year has brought us even more *closer* together as a family.

Grammarly suggested me to change it to closely, stating it doesn't fit the current context.

Comment: I would prefer "even closer". "Even more close" is possible but not as good. Grammarly is wrong because you need an adjective and "closely" is an adverb.

Comment: Grammarly is wrong. _closer_ is the correct choice.

Comment: The question is now why did the app suggest that "closely" was a better fit?

Comment: @user405662 - But without _more_!  Grammarly suggested _closely_ because _more closer_ is definitely wrong, since _closer_ is already a comparative.

Comment: Why the downvote? A comment with the reason for downvotes would help new contributors like me to correct ourselves in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammarly is mistaken, the best solution is

> We feel the past year has brought us even **closer** together as a family

I think that the app was fixing the nonstandard "more closer" which is considered ungrammatical by many native speakers and grammarians.

It is redundant to modify an adjective that is already in the
comparative form with "more",  e.g "more closer", "more sooner" and  (especially) "more more important" which careful speakers will avoid. Instead, you can use "**much**" or "**far**" to modify comparative forms, e.g.

1. *It brought us **much closer** together*
2. *The promotion arrived **far sooner** than I anticipated*.

The determiner "more" can modify an **adverb**, e.g. “***more*** **closely**”, “***more*** **quickly**”, and “***more*** **importantly**”. Thus the following is also acceptable:

3. It brought us **more closely** together

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what _it brought us more closely together_ means. I could understand, for example, what _we worked more closely together_ would mean, since _more closely_ can be a manner adjunct of us working. But can it be a manner adjunct of bringing us in _it brought us more closely together_? I think what we need after _brought us_ there is not a manner adjunct but a complement such as _(even) closer_.

Comment: Yes, "It brought us more closely together" is quite [uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brought+us+more+closely%2Cbrought+us+closer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrought%20us%20more%20closely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrought%20us%20closer%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @JK2 "bring (it/them/us) more closely together" may not be commonly used, but it's not ungrammatical. What's more I see no significant difference in meaning between, *"they must work more closely together"* and "*they must work closer together*” or "*the tragedy brought/drew them more closely together*" and "*the tragedy brought them closer together*”

Comment: @fev "quite uncommon" I think is an understatement. Note that the gap in the ngram keeps widening to a point where the "quite uncommon" borders on ungrammatical.

Comment: @JK2 https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brought%20us%20more%20closely%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1969,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en It's used, and I said it was *acceptable*, I clearly stated which form was the best solution.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brought+us+more+closer%22&lr=lang_en&biw=1280&bih=609&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1969%2Ccd_max%3A2019%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03mxJKtkOUXOKOfKKJoPkCdX3ULRw%3A1625451114436&ei=amriYLeTGtav9QPDoqfYBg&oq=%22brought+us+more+closer%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2341.3531.0.4747.6.6.0.0.0.0.131.624.0j5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.n021imm_FZk I've searched for "brought us more closer", and it's also used. Does that mean it's "acceptable"? But you said _more closer_ "is considered ungrammatical by many native speakers and grammarians."

Comment: @jK2 The instances of "brought us more closer" reported by Google Books are far fewer than those I found for  "brought us more closer". I never disputed people say "more closer",  that's why I said that it is **considered ungrammatical**. You are free to focus all your attention on the last sentence, which I threw in at the last minute showing how **more closely**  can be used. But I am willing to substitute  the idiom "bring somebody together" with a suitable verb such as *work* or  *live* if that will make you happier.

Comment: All I'm saying is, just because you have Google Books examples doesn't necessarily mean it's not "nonstandard", which you say "more closer" is in your own answer. True, "brought us more closer" has fewer instances than "brought us more closely", but the latter also includes legitimate examples such as "brought us more closely related...", and if you click through the end of the search results you'll know that the results are not dramatically different. "Far fewer" is how I'd describe "brought us more closely" compared to "brought us closer" in the Ngram.